# Filter observable array when populated with type model

Tags: knockout.js

I am creating an e-commerce site, and I have a model of type product which holds all information on each product my customer wishes to sell. This product model is pushed to an observable array to which is displayed on the screen to the user via foreach:. This is all working fine.

I wish to have controls such as checkbox/radio buttons which will filter the array on screen. For example by color or size. Reading the tutorials this is straight forward to do if dealing with a linear array of either numbers or words. I have having difficulty translating this to work with a model. I would like to select for instance color is red, then the observable array would filter to where product.color = red within the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Put the code so people don't have to read your mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of us trying to help, it would be very useful to get a better idea of what you're trying to do. Please share your code when asking questions in the future as this will help us assist you better and reduce our guesswork. Either way, I went ahead and created a jsfiddle to demo what I thought you might be going for.

http://jsfiddle.net/9cVjv/2/

This demo uses knockout **computables** to handle the filtering. Computables are observables which are computed by some given function. In my example, I simply perform some filtering using base JS array functions (using **ko.utils** functions is probably better, but I wanted to keep this clear for people who are not familiar with knockout).

**JS:**

```
function FilterViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'widget', color: 'blue', size: 'large' },
        { name: 'wigglit', color: 'red', size: 'large' },
        { name: 'gadget', color: 'yellow', size: 'small' },
        { name: 'wadget', color: 'blue', size: 'large' },
        { name: 'wizzle', color: 'blue', size: 'small' },
        { name: 'fizzle', color: 'green', size: 'small' },
        { name: 'gigglit', color: 'blue', size: 'small' },
        { name: 'fidget', color: 'red', size: 'large' },
        { name: 'midget', color: 'red', size: 'large' },
        { name: 'madget', color: 'blue', size: 'large' },
    ]);
    self.selectedColor = ko.observableArray('');
    self.selectedSize = ko.observable('');

    self.filteredProducts = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.products().filter(function (value) {
            var isInSet = true;

            // if the size doesn't match, don't include this one
            if(self.selectedSize() != '' && self.selectedSize() != null &&
               self.selectedSize() != value.size)
               isInSet = false;

            // if the colors don't match, don't include this one
            if(self.selectedColor() != '' &&
               self.selectedColor() != null && 
               self.selectedColor() != value.color) {
                   isInSet = false;
            }

            return isInSet;
        });
    });

    self.colorOptions = ko.computed(function() {
        var colorChoices = self.products().map(function(value) {
            return value.color;
        }).filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
            return self.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });

        //combine a blank choice and the colors from products 
        return (['']).concat(colorChoices);
    });
    self.sizeOptions = ko.computed(function() {      
        var sizeChoices = self.products().map(function(value) {
            return value.size;
        }).filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
            return self.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });

        //combine a blank choice and the sizes from products
        return (['']).concat(sizeChoices);
    });
}

var viewModel = new FilterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blockItem">
    <p>Color: 
        <select data-bind="options: colorOptions, value: selectedColor"></select>
    </p>
    <p>Size: 
        <select data-bind="options: sizeOptions, value: selectedSize"></select>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="blockItem">
    <p><b>PRODUCTS</b></p>
    <!-- ko foreach: filteredProducts -->
        <p class="blockItem">
            <b>Name:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>,
            <b>Color:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.color"></span>,
            <b>Size:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.size"></span>
        </p>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.blockItem {
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ko.utils](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) functions to filter your array, the example on that page just has a single filter. If you want to expand this to filter on different fields, that wouldn't be too hard, but as Aeolos says in the comments, we'd need you to post some code to be able to help with that.

However, taking a punt, you could create a Filter object, containing the field name to filter against, and the filter value, and add each active filter to an observableArray of filters:

```
//filter the items using the filter text
viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    if (filters().length === 0) {
        return this.items();
    } else {
        var results = this.items();
        for(var i = 0; i < filters().length; i++)
        {
            var filter = filters()[i];
            results = ko.utils.arrayFilter(results, function(item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item[filter.name]().toLowerCase(), filter.value);
            });
        }
        return results;
    }
}, viewModel);
```

This isn't in any way tested, but it might give you an idea of what to do.